# Scala - Add elements based on logic

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala.
I have a function that accepts a string and based on different logics, I need to create a Seq of String with all permutations.
Example - input string is `00US_India0234`. The result will be `Seq` of:

```
US // Condition - if string contains "US"
India // Condition - if string contains "India"
234 // Condition - if string contains number and trim
US_India // One more condition to keep countries intact and so on
```

Code tried so far which I didn't work

```
val retSeq: Seq[String] = Seq.empty
if myStr contains "US" retSeq +: "US"
```

I have the conditions in place but adding to Seq is not possible and I do not want to create a `var`.

Comment: Could you post some of the code you have tried?

Comment: I am new and couldnt find out where to start. I do not want to create multiple Seq

Comment: you want this? `input: 00US_India0234` -> `output: Seq(Us, India, 0234, US_India)`?

Comment: yes. And this would be based on some conditions and without using mutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a list of tuples containing predicates and functions to process your input you want to potentially apply and append to `Seq`:

```
val numberRegex = "([0-9]{4,})".r

val predicates = List[(String => Boolean, String => String)](
    (s => s.contains("US"), _  => "US"),
    (s => s.contains("India"), s => s.toUpperCase()),
    (s => numberRegex.findFirstIn(s).nonEmpty, s => numberRegex.findFirstIn(s).head)
 )
```

And then you need to just create a method to build up `Seq`:

```
def process(s: String): Seq[String] = predicates.collect{
   case (predicate, value) if predicate(s) => value(s)
}

process("00US_India0234") //List(US, 00US_INDIA0234, 0234)
```

Comment: How would the condition look like if instead of const string, I want to call a function? I tried (s => s.contains("US"), trim(s)) but it doesnt work

Comment: You will probably need to change the type of list. Can you edit your question with example? It would be much easier.

Comment: (s => s.matches(".*\\d+.*"), "0234") should return the number and not hardcoded string

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version, using `RegEx`:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val input = "00US_India0234"

val reg = "([A-Z]{2})_?([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)".r

val a = for (m <- reg.findAllMatchIn(input)) yield m.subgroups

println(a.toVector.flatten)

// Out: Vector(US, India, 0234)
```

You can test it in [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/79fZkGy/3)

Comment: I am not looking for regex as I would have multiple conditions which might not be achievable. But thanks for providing another option